# Is there any Limitation on loading native google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the following code to load native google map app into my project:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?"
                            + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884"
                            + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355"));

            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

            startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any limitation or pre-requisties there i should know.
Because its working in my laptop emulator but not working on PC emulator.
I only load the native google map app, it should work on any emulator.
Is something i am missing here ??

I am getting blank black screen and **logcat error** is:

> 04-16 16:20:06.051: D/PhoneWindow(841): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@450274e8 has no id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is maybe one of your emulators set to the building target „Google APIs (Google Inc.) – API Level XY“ and one to „Android A.B – API Level XY“? For Google Maps API, you should use the first one.

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry but in this case I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

Firstly the above line is not need because you are loading native map. and once check whether are you able launch maps application in your pc emulator because these also might be problem of proxy to your pc.

Comment: If i dont setClassName as above, google map open in uri which i dont want,by setting the class name it load native google map which i prefer better.